# Gunicorn worker getting exit in airflow web server with Received signal: 15. Closing gunicorn

Tags: python, airflow, gunicorn, airflow-webserver

Gunicorn worker getting exit in airflow web server with Received signal: 15. Closing gunicorn. while installing airflow on kubernetes.

Scheduler and other DB migration and user sync pod are running fine only web server pod are restarting with below error.

### Here some details :

Airflow version       : 2.6.3
Airflow Chart version : 8.8.0
Executor              : KubernetesExecutor
Airflow Image         : apache/airflow:2.6.3-python3.10
Chart repo            : https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts.git

What could be the issue we have only changes some configuration like Executor to KubernetesExecutor and DB detail. in same environment airflow version 2.2.3 working with same configuration.

```
[2023-09-13 10:48:36 +0000] [46] [INFO] Listening at: https://0.0.0.0:8080 (46)
[2023-09-13 10:48:36 +0000] [46] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-09-13 10:48:36 +0000] [154] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 154
[2023-09-13 10:48:36 +0000] [155] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 155
[2023-09-13 10:48:36 +0000] [156] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 156
[2023-09-13 10:48:36 +0000] [157] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 157
[2023-09-13 10:49:04 +0000] [157] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 157)
[2023-09-13 10:49:04 +0000] [155] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 155)
[2023-09-13 10:49:04 +0000] [156] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 156)
[2023-09-13 10:49:04 +0000] [154] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 154)
[2023-09-13 10:49:04 +0000] [46] [INFO] Handling signal: term
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
Access Logformat: 
=================================================================
[2023-09-13T10:49:04.697+0000] {webserver_command.py:432} INFO - Received signal: 15. Closing gunicorn.
[2023-09-13 10:49:07 +0000] [46] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

What could be the issue we have only changes some configuration like Executor to KubernetesExecutor and DB detail. in same environment airflow version 2.2.3 working with same configuration.

Comment: Any updates/news?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

All images have been updated to 2.7.3-python3.8

Added 7Gi of memory to resources and increased the initialDelaySeconds of the Liveness.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).